# Android open pdf in webview

Tags: android, pdf

I try to open .pdf file's in webview. I wrote code which can show pdf in webview.

I am using "http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=" google drive to open pdf files on docs.google but i want to change the webview design for example I want to change the title, color etc. of my webview.

My webview looks like this:

http://postimg.org/image/cpb46c80x/

**Code**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{

    public WebView web;
```

...

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    // web.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);

    web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

    String pdfURL = "http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/37098169/Course%20Brochures/AND101.pdf";
    web.loadUrl("http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url="
            + pdfURL);
    // setContentView(web);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: thanks but i also tryed this but i do not know how i can to change design.for example,webview's tiitle color is blue and how i can to change color ? if you know how i can to change help please